# Differentiate Piecewise Functions

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}x^3 \sin\frac{1}{x}, & x > 0\\ x \sin(x) & x \leq 0 \end{array}\right.$$

How do I find $f'(x)$? I tried using the definition of derivatives but it got me nowhere.

Comment: Can you not just define the derivatives in a piecewise fashion?

Comment: is that possible? so the domains for each derivative remains the same? @mathtastic

Comment: http://math2.uncc.edu/~bjwichno/spring2010/math1121/Lecture_Notes/unit_1/Lectures/lec_piecewise_rule.htm

Comment: That link has a few nice concrete examples of how you might treat the derivative of a piecewise-defined function

Comment: @mathtastic: Does that page have an error for the derivative of $\sin(x^2)$?

Comment: @Amzoti - Actually, yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\ne 0$ we have:
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
3x^2\sin\frac1x-x\cos\frac1x &\mbox{ if } x>0\\
\sin x+x\cos x &\mbox{ if } x<0
\end{cases}.
$$
The only problem is at $x=0$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}&=&\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^-}x^2\sin\frac1x=0;\\
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}&=&\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\sin x=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and $f'(0)=0$.

Hence
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
3x^2\sin\frac1x-x\cos\frac1x &\mbox{ if } x>0\\
\sin x+x\cos x &\mbox{ if } x\le0
\end{cases}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** : You applied first principle of derivatives that's all good you will get the left hand derivative answer but in the right hand derivative what do you think the range of sine is??

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is derivable on $\mathbb R\backslash \{0\}$, then we just have to chec the derivability in $x=0$.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin x=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=0$$

The last result is justified by
$$\left|x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right|\leq \left|x^2\right|\to 0\text{ if }x\to 0^-.$$

Then $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=0$$ and thus it's derivable.